# Maven: Deploying an HTML form page with a Response Java EE that prints results with POST

Tags: java, html, maven, jakarta-ee

I have an HTML file that has a form:

```
<head>

</head>

<body>
<h1>Voter Registration Page</h1>

<p>Please fill out all information below to register as a voter.</p>

<form method = "post" action = "results">
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" ><br>
Address: <input type="text" id="address" name="address"><br>
City: <input type="text" id="city" name="city"><br>
State: <input type="text" id="state" name="state"><br>
Zip: <input type="text" id="zip"name="zip"><br>
Phone Number: <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone"><br><br>

Affiliation:<br>
<input type="radio" name="affil" value="Democrat">Democrat<br>
<input type="radio" name="affil" value="Green Party">Green Party<br>
<input type="radio" name="affil" value="Liberterian">Liberterian<br>
<input type="radio" name="affil" value="Republican">Republican<br>
<input type="radio" name="affil" value="Unafilliated">Unafiiliated<br>

<br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Using Maven and JAVA EE I'm trying to use POST to make a results page when the user clicks Submit on the HTML form:

web.xml

```
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>results</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controller.Response</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>results</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/results</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Current Java Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class Response extends HttpServlet{

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException{
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
         out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head><title>demolet</title></head>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("<p>First Name:</p>"); 
out.println("<p>Last Name:</p>");
out.println("<p>Address:</p>");
out.println("<p>Phone:</p>");
out.println("<p>Afiiliation:</p>");
    out.println("</body></html>");
    out.close();


    }
}
```

However, the main problems I'm having are:

1.I'm trying to figure out is how to pass in the values answered in the HTMl file to the Java file so it can properly write a html file with the results.

2.I'm new to Java servlets and xml so I have a feeling my set up is incorrect somwhere.

If anyone can offer any help for any of these two problems, that would be great. Thanks.

Don't worry about the Maven part for now, I know how to use the command line to set up my project and see results and stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read `<form />` field value from `request` parameter.

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     throws IOException{
   PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
   .......

   String firstname=request.getParameter("firstname");    

   out.println("<p>First Name:"+ firstname +"</p>"); 

    .......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML form data can be fetched using the request object:

```
Enumeration paramNames = request.getParameterNames(); 
while(paramNames.hasMoreElements()) {   
    System.out.println((String)paramNames.nextElement()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All the data that is submitted as a part of GET/POST will become part of a `HttpServletRequest` object. You can use the same to fetch the values. Refer [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) for more details.

It is also good practice not to write HTML in .java files and not to write java in .jsp files.